# Cannot find name 'StripeCheckoutStatic'?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I need to add the payment gateway for my application and I am try to integrate stripe

I have imported the following npm packeage only. and does not add any file to app.module.ts files

> npm install stripe --save

then I try to add to implement it in the payment.component.ts file,
this is the only place i uses stripe ,no where any imports are added

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { PaymentService } from './payment.service';

declare var StripeCheckout: StripeCheckoutStatic;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment',
  templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css'],
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  handler: StripeCheckoutHandler;

  constructor(private paymentService: PaymentService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: environment.straipekey,
      image: 'some-image',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: (token) => {
        this.paymentService.updateTokenWithDatabase(token, 12300);
      },
    });

    console.log(this.handler);
  }

  onPayment() {
    this.handler.open({
      name: 'PayMe',
      description: 'Pay with me',
      amount: 1500,
    });
  }
}
```

when i try to execute onPayment() method error occur

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'StripeCheckoutStatic'
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'StripeCheckoutHandler'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal/Command prompt, install it by running:

```
npm install --save @types/stripe-checkout
```

You might need to declare it in the **devDependencies** in your **package.json** file too, by adding:

```json
"@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.3",
```

Comment: Use `--save-dev` instead of `--save` to put it in `devDependencies` right away